How to assign individual 'Paypal Add to Cart' to individual html check boxes
I have a check box setup that changes an image dependant on which checkbox you click (displays a different colour).
I would like to assign a separate 'PayPal Add to Cart' to each checkbox, so the viewer chooses the colour, then clicks the PayPal button to buy the item selected.
The HTML code:
    <div class="colors">
    <div class="ColourLabel"><div class="c5"></div><span>Moonwalk<br>Grey</span></div>
    <div class="ColourLabel"><div class="c9"></div><span>Midnight<br>Black</span></div>
    <div class="ColourLabel"><div class="c10"></div><span>Volcanic<br>Orange</span></div>
    <div class="ColourLabel"><div class="c11"></div><span>Chili<br>Red</span></div>
    <div class="ColourLabel"><div class="c12"></div><span>Lapisluxury<br>Blue</span></div>
    <div class="ColourLabel"><div class="c13"></div><span>Thunder<br>Grey</span></div>
    <div class="ColourLabel"><div class="c7"></div><span>British Racing<br>Green</span></div>
    <div class="ColourLabel"><div class="c8"></div><span>Blazing<br>Red</span></div>
    <div class="ColourLabel"><div class="c2"></div><span>Pepper<br>White</span></div>
    <div class="ColourLabel"><div class="c3"></div><span>White<br>Silver</span></div>
    </div>

A snippet of the  Script Code:
    $(".product2 .c5").click(function(){
    $(".product2 .c1").css("box-shadow","none");
    $(".product2 .c2").css("box-shadow","none");
    $(".product2 .c3").css("box-shadow","none");
    $(".product2 .c4").css("box-shadow","none");
    $(".product2 .c5").css("box-shadow","0 0 0 2px #0D1F2D, 0 0 0 3.5px #CB3843");
    $(".product2 .c6").css("box-shadow","none");
    $(".product2 .c7").css("box-shadow","none");
    $(".product2 .c8").css("box-shadow","none");
    $(".product2 .c9").css("box-shadow","none");
    $(".h2").animate({opacity:0},function(){
    $(".h2").attr("src","img/Ark/ARK MG.webp");
    });
    $(".h2").animate({opacity:1});
    });

Have tried assigning Paypal containers like so but it will only display the first in line:
    <div id="paypal-container-SOME-ID">
    <div class="ColourLabel"><div class="c5"></div><span>Moonwalk<br>Grey</span></div>
    </div>
    <div id="paypal-container-ANOTHER-ID">
    <div class="ColourLabel"><div class="c9"></div><span>Midnight<br>Black</span></div>
    </div>

And the Paypal Script like so:
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=MY-ID&components=hosted-buttons&disable-funding=venmo&currency=GBP"></script>
    <script>
    paypal.HostedButtons({
    hostedButtonId: "SOME-ID",
    }).render("#paypal-container-SOME-ID")
    </script>
    <script>
    paypal.HostedButtons({
    hostedButtonId: "ANOTHER-ID",
    }).render("paypal-container-ANOTHER-ID")
    </script>

I am open to advice as a better way to work around this as it seems very messy for a user - selecting a checkbox to view the item - then having to use a dropdown menu (set up in Paypal buttons) to buy an item?
(I have Attached a screen shot of what I mean)
Thanks
Working javascript now:
$(".product2 .c5").click(function(){
$(".product2 .c1").css("box-shadow","none");
$(".product2 .c2").css("box-shadow","none");
$(".product2 .c3").css("box-shadow","none");
$(".product2 .c4").css("box-shadow","none");
$(".product2 .c5").css("box-shadow","0 0 0 2px #0D1F2D, 0 0 0 3.5px #CB3843");
$(".product2 .c6").css("box-shadow","none");
$(".product2 .c7").css("box-shadow","none");
$(".product2 .c8").css("box-shadow","none");
$(".product2 .c9").css("box-shadow","none");
$(".product2 .c10").css("box-shadow","none");
$(".product2 .c11").css("box-shadow","none");
$(".product2 .c12").css("box-shadow","none");
$(".product2 .c13").css("box-shadow","none");
$(".product2 .c14").css("box-shadow","none");
$(".PpButton .c145").animate({opacity:0},function(){
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
'beforeend',
'<a href="https://www.paypal.com/ncp/payment/LINK" target="_blank"><img class".PpButton" src="img/Web/paypal.webp"></a>');});
$(".PpButton .c145").animate({opacity:1});
$(".h2").animate({opacity:0},function(){
$(".h2").attr("src","img/Ark/ARK MG.webp");
});
$(".h2").animate({opacity:1});
});


Amended javascript code - to show individual Paypal button per .product2 .c(number).

Href link has to be _blank or Paypal won't accept it.

Am I right that you want, that each checkbox has a separate PayPal "Add to Cart" button?

Hi @z|E|o - that's a good question, and something I didn't add. The checkboxes work fine - I am guessing what I really need is Paypal buttons that show/hide dependant on what checkbox is ticked (each links to that colour in Paypal individually)

It's going to be a bit hacky since "Pay link or button" hosted buttons are not designed to pass data selected outside them, but it is possible to inspect the rendered HTML and write javascript that will adjust the selected dropdown accordingly when the checkboxes are clicked.
No one can attempt to do this for you when the values in your question are obfuscated, however.

Alternate solutions of creating a hosted button for each color and only showing one based on the color selected are going to be more awkward, to say the least.
A standard checkout with a backend offers much more flexibility than hosted buttons. However it obviously requires a backend calling PayPal APIs.

Thanks Preston - I have added a new line in the Javascript code to trigger showing the button (just a border), which seems to show up - is it possible to replace it with a paypal button which has the href linked to it? Tried altering this in javascript (but javascript isnt my thing really)

I don't know what you mean. With respect to my answer, your actual website's code and actual button code will be required to make it work.

Apologies, I understand I am being vague, but I think I've sussed it - will post code above. Thanks both

So you're going to create a link for each option and have their be an additional payment step on reaching a PayPal page? Works well enough I suppose.

Yes indeed - more coding, but it just looks more user friendly, I think - Thanks @Preston PHX
